# Assign position in array as react key?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native

I have an array which consists of different strings. I want to map through it and display it in React. React does not like it when two strings are the same.

My question is this: Is there a way for me to map through the array and assign the position of the element in the array (0,1,2,3..) as the key? I am not sure how I would access this? Can I?

```
let renderthis = this.props.myreducer.somearray.map((element) =>
  <span key={what can I put here?}>{element} </span>
);
```

I tried this btw, but it did not work:

```
let renderthis = this.props.myreducer.somearray.map((element, i) =>
  <span key={i}>{element} </span>
);
```

> Warning: flattenChildren(...): Encountered two children with the same
>   key, `.1:$afaf`. Child keys must be unique; when two children share a
>   key, only the first child will be used.

Comment: The second argument to the `map` callback is an index.

Comment: thanks. see my edit, if this is what you mean. I tried that but I get a warning that the elements have duplicate keys. But maybe what I am doing there is wrong?

Comment: It's some other elements that have duplicate keys then.

Comment: I dont think so. I am getting that error at precisely the moment I add a duplicate element to that array.

Comment: Not sure where you took the `.1:$afaf`. `i` is a number there.

Comment: Yes, I also don't know, I also expected a number. It does not seem to be one though.

Comment: "It does not seem to be one though" --- prove it :-)

Comment: Alright, I just found out my mistake, I just confused two input fields.... well! So you were right, your solution works. If you want to and post it as an answer, I would select that. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Array.prototype.map` callback accepts the second argument as an item index.

That means that if you simply need unique keys per a collection of element and you don't have any other values that are naturally unique you can simply do:

```
let renderthis = this.props.myreducer.somearray.map((element, i) =>
  <span key={i}>{element} </span>
);
```